# Qt Jambi, Java UI Editor, Displaying a picture?

Tags: java, qt, qgraphicsview, qt-jambi

I am using QT Jambi to make the homepage for my java program, but currently I cannot figure out how to put a picture on the homescreen. Currently, I have a QTGraphicsView and I have created a resource with my picture in it. When I right click on the QTGraphicsView and go to EditTooltip/whatisThis... it lets me select a picture from my resource to add, but it doesnt display on the QTGraphicsView.

Does anyone know how to put a picture in the QTGraphicsView from a resource?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry this is a bad question, All you have to do to put a picture in QT-Jambi is make a label and then put the picture into the label.

Comment: That's not a bad question just because you found the answer :). Put under there and accept your own answer. When someone with the same problem finds it via google they will be very glad you did :)

Comment: Fish is right: as a friendly reminder please answer your own question and accept it so that helpers and searchers won't waste time.